Should primitives whose solutions involve logarithm functions specify absolute value for negative arguments?
I'm reviewing (for my own personal satisfaction) a number of source works which give tables of primitives for standard functions in the real domain.
I understand that in the real domain $\displaystyle \int \frac {\mathrm d u} u = \ln |u| + C$.
However, many source works do not bother to indicate that the argument of the logarithm needs to be treated with the absolute value when negative.
Murray Spiegel's Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables (Schaum, 1968) puts a caveat in place ("in general, to extend formulas to cases where $u < 0$ as well, replace $\ln u$ by $\ln |u|$") but it is often the case where this is not done.
Hence you see many tables of integrals with things like:
$$\int \sec x \, \mathrm d x = \ln (\sec x + \tan x) + C$$
instead of the "correct" form:
$$\int \sec x \, \mathrm d x = \ln |\sec x + \tan x| + C$$
Would it be appropriate to flag this practice up as "incorrect" and classify such occurrences as mistakes?
Or is there a philosophical approach to calculus in which such attention to detail does not matter, and it is perfectly adequate to merely quote the primitive without the absolute value having been applied (notwithstanding Spiegel's caveat)?
In Spiegel's Advanced Calculus (SI edition) of $1974$, for example, he gives the primitives in his table in full correct absolute value form.
But take Margaret Gow's A course in pure mathematics of $1960$ as a random example, where in her working she does not mention the negative case, nor does she specify that the results apply to a positive argument only. To me that is a bit slapdash.
The Dictionary of Mathematics by Borowski and Borwein ($1989$) takes this approach, as does the Penguin Dictionary of Mathematics by David Nelson (both 2nd and 4th editions, $1998$ and $2008$ respectively) although the latter is irritatingly inconsistent by giving $\displaystyle \int \cot x \, \mathrm d x = \ln |\sin x| + C$, for example, but then on the very next line $\displaystyle \int \sec x \, \mathrm d x = \ln (\sec x + \tan x) + C$.
What is the general consensus of opinion on this. How much, really, when presenting educational material for general public consumption, does it actually matter?
